# Join query based upon MIN values on join table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table structure like this (simplified):

**Artist**

- ArtistID
- Name

**ArtistEvent**

- ArtistID
- EventID

**Event**

- EventID
- Name

**EventDates**

- EventID
- Date

**EventGroup**

- EventID
- GroupID

**Group**

- Group ID

I want to pull out all artists that have upcoming events based upon the group ID (so group->EventGroup->Event->ArtistEvent->Artist. Simple, this is done and working.

I also would like to show the next event that the artist is playing at (ie the Event with the MIN(date) that is part of this join.

As we're already including Events within the join it seems I should be able to get the details of what the event is (simple, can include this within the select) but we need to ensure it's the FIRST date (by MIN(Date)) as there may be multiple ones (which are disregarded as we group on ArtistID to discard the rest)

Until now I had one query that pulls out all the linked artists, and another which runs in a loop in our code and pulls out the next event for each artist but I want to know if its possible to do this in one query?

I can get it returning events if I do:

```
SELECT artist.name, MIN(EventDate.Date), Event.Name 
FROM Artist 
INNER JOIN ArtistEvent ON Artist.ArtistID = ArtistEvent.ArtistID 
INNER JOIN Event ON Event.EventID = ArtistEvent.EventID
INNER JOIN EventGroup ON EventGroup.EventID = Event.EventID 
INNER JOIN EventDates ON EventDates.EventID = Event.EventID 
WHERE EventGroup.GroupID = 1234
```

BUT this seems too simple - will the Event.Name that's being returned definitely corresponds to the same event that's showing for `EventDates.Date`?

I think I've confused myself and need a fresh pair of eyes?

Thanks

Comment: What about past events? If you have them on database, MIN wouldn't work for you.

Comment: Don't you need a GROUP BY clause, even in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

how about this one:

```
SELECT artist.name, MIN(EventDate.Date)
FROM Artist  
INNER JOIN ArtistEvent ON Artist.ArtistID = ArtistEvent.ArtistID  
INNER JOIN Event ON ArtistEvent.EventID  
INNER JOIN EventGroup ON EventGroup.EventID = Event.EventID  
INNER JOIN EventDates ON EventDates.EventID = Event.EventID  
WHERE EventGroup.GroupID = 1234 
and eventdate.date > sysdate
group by artist.name
```

Comment: You haven't fixed the inaccurate ON condition after 'INNER JOIN Event'.

Comment: Yes that's the basis of what im working with, but I also need to pull back some additional info on the Event - so if I put Event.Name in the select, will it be the correct details? Bearing on mind that Event:EventDates is 1:Many

Comment: @Ben: yes - if you fix the invalid join condition to `INNER JOIN Event ON Event.EventID = ArtistEvent.EventID`, then the event name you get will be correct.  (If MySQL lets you get away with the join as written, then it is doing you no favours - you are getting a Cartesian product where you did not want or need one, and things might go AWOL as a result.)

Comment: You can't include on select clause a field that is not include on the group clause. If you do it mysql return a random value inside this group for the missing field.

Comment: yes, i omitted the event name from the grouping - if you include that you will get a set of the first schedule for all named events per user instead of just the next one.  you could wrap this result set and also match where the min dates were equal to pull back the name.

Comment: @Jonathan the JOIN clause is just a typo. So I seem to be getting conflicting replies here, @Jonathan says it will work, @Borja says it won't. I've tried runnig and it does work with Event.Name in the select and not in the Group By but wondering if its accurate or a random result that doesnt match with the correct event as suggested by @Borja?

Comment: @Randy - could you elaborate on your last answer? As explained above this 'works' but I'm not sure the Event.Name will  be from the same record as MIN(EventDate.Date) - it seems it may be random as you say, how can I ensure they match?

Comment: @Ben: In standard SQL, you have to list all non-aggregate columns in the GROUP BY clause.  In MySQL, you get away without doing so, but I've not investigated what happens when you don't list them all.  I think @Borja is indicating that the syntax is wrong, and for most DBMS he would be correct; fortunately for you, MySQL is not 'most DBMS'.